# "Incompatible saved desktop has been ignored" in IDA

Tags: ida, tools

When I launch IDA for the first time, I move my windows to reflect my perfect window setup. Then I save the desktop and set it as default, plus I additionally save a named backup.

After this, I close IDA, launch it again, and everything works.

However, after some time (days-weeks) I get message: "incompatible saved desktop has been ignored" and my desktop is completely reset to default. Restoring the desktop from the backup results in the same message. This has already happened a couple of times and each time it was very annoying. What is the reason for this behavior and how can I keep my desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is shown if a user changes screen resolution between IDA restarts, which happens particularly often when using IDA inside a virtual machine (which gets arbitrary resolution unless it's launched fullscreen). So to keep the desktop, make sure to maintain the same screen resolution when launching IDA.

I haven't tested if the default desktop is overwritten as soon as IDA starts with different resolution than previous session. Having a named backup for this scenario certainly won't hurt.